# How to add parameters to existing model when objects already saved?

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

I have a Bill class which contains a few instances of bills that are saved in a plist file to the documents directory using NSKeyedArchiver.

```
class Bill: NSObject, NSCoding {

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Name") as! String
    moPayment = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "Payment")
    super.init()
  }

  override init() {
    super.init()
  }

  var name = "Bill Name"
  var moPayment = 0.0

  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "Name")
    aCoder.encode(moPayment, forKey: "Payment")
  }
}

func saveBillItems(_ bills: [Bill]) {
  let data = NSMutableData()
  let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
  archiver.encode(bills, forKey: "BillItems")
  archiver.finishEncoding()
  data.write(to: dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
}

func loadBillItems() {
    let path = dataFilePath()
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path) {

        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
        bills = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "BillItems") as! [Bill]
        unarchiver.finishDecoding()
    }
}
```

All of this works as expected but now I am trying to add an additional parameter to record paidStatus.

```
class Bill: NSObject, NSCoding {

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    ...
    status = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Status") as! PaidStatus
    super.init()
  }

  ...

  var status = PaidStatus.unpaid

  enum PaidStatus {
    case overdue
    case upcoming
    case unpaid
    case paid
  }

  ...

  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    ...
    aCoder.encode(status, forKey: "Status")
  }
}

func saveBillItems(_ bills: [Bill]) {
  ...
}

func loadBillItems() {
  ...
}
```

When I try to run the app now, I get an error: "Unexpectedly found nil..."

```
status = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Status") as! PaidStatus
```

due to trying to load existing bill objects that don't have this parameter.

Is there a way to add this parameter to my existing objects without having to delete them and recreate them again from scratch?

Comment: Don't use the forced downcast; use a conditional Downcast possible with a nil coalescing operator

Comment: Doing that will give me a compiler error since status cannot take optional values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your object may not have a value, you need to use an optional downcast, not a forced downcast.  Since `status` is not an optional, you can use a nil coalescing operator to provide a default value

```
status = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Status") as? PaidStatus ?? .unpaid
```

Comment: This seems to work however I am getting an unrecognized selector sent to instance encodeWithCoder. I believe this may be related to encoding an enum however and a separate question.